How windy is it really on the Con Dao islands in January?
I am planning a trip with my family to Vietnam in January. We had planned to visit Con Dao for about 5 days, and we were really looking forward to that part of the trip.
However, having read various travel blogs, it seems that it is really windy on the Con Dao islands in January. Some say you won't be able to be on a beach due to high winds and sand, while others say that January is a great time to visit the Con Dao islands.
The nice and warm climate of southern Vietnam is absolutely one of the reasons we chose Vietnam. However, I'd be interested in hearing from someone who's been to Con Dao in January (and who's not selling the destination).
Right now we're looking at Phu Quoc instead, but it really doesn't have the same feel to it (although the eastern side of the island seem to be slighly less "invaded" by huge resorts).
Is it really THAT windy on the Con Dao islands in Janunary?

After I wrote this question, I stumbled upon https://girlswanderlust.com/con-dao-vietnam-everything-you-need-to-know-before-visiting which is fairly clear on January not being an ideal month to visit Con Dao : "I visited Con Dao in January and this was definitely not a good time to visit Con Dao. The weather was dry, which was good, but it was very windy and the sea was rough. Ferries to and from the island were canceled throughout the week, no boat excursions were organized and because of the wind, sometimes I couldn’t ride the scooter around the island."

I've never been there, but a quick google turned up this link for the weather statistics at the airport on Con Dao.
It shows that for January the average wind is from the NE and the chances of wind are:
0-1 mph => 12%
1-8 mph => 86%
8-25 mph => 3%
Whether or not this is suitable beach weather is going to depend on what side of the island you are on, what activities you want to partake, and how wind tolerant you are.
I've also seen that the windy season is from November to the end of January, and that for the coming weekend the forecast is for wind speeds in the mid 20's and gusts up to 30 mph.
Looking at a map of the island, the airport is sort of protected by mountains, so the wind speeds there could differ significantly from the beaches.  But the resort areas also seem to be protected by mountains a bit.
But statistics are statistics and not the conditions you'd experience when actually there.
